# An object which is accessible by all Scenes in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I have my own `ClientGame` class and I want to add an object of this class, which will be accessible by all `Scenes` in cocos2d-x. I tried following methods, but they don't work.

1) I create a `BaseScene` class which contains my class object and inherits cocos2d::Layer. Then, every scene inherit this `BaseScene`. It compiles, but the window screen just show up and turn off right away.

2) I tried to inherit both `cocos2d::Layer` and `BaseScene` at the sametime.
It compiles, but it produces same result as above.

What is the best way to create an object which is accessible by all `Scenes`?
Here is my code.

> BaseScene.h

```
#include "cocos2d.h"
#include "ClientGame.h"


class BaseScene
{
public:

private: 
  ClientGame mClientGame;

};
```

> ClientGame.h

```
class ClientGame
{
public:
    ClientGame(void);
    ~ClientGame(void);    
    ClientNetwork* network; 
    void sendActionPackets(int action);
    void sendLineDestroyed();
    char network_data[MAX_PACKET_SIZE];
    void update();
    void clientLoop();

};
```

> IntroScene.h

```
#include "cocos2d.h"
#include "BaseScene.h"


class IntroScene : public cocos2d::Layer, public BaseScene
{
public:
    // there's no 'id' in cpp, so we recommend returning the class instance pointer
    static cocos2d::Scene* createScene();

    // Here's a difference. Method 'init' in cocos2d-x returns bool, instead of returning 'id' in cocos2d-iphone
    virtual bool init();

    // a selector callback
    void menuCloseCallback(cocos2d::Ref* pSender);

    // implement the "static create()" method manually
    CREATE_FUNC(IntroScene);

    cocos2d::Sprite* pTetrisLogo;
    cocos2d::Sprite* pCloseNormal;

    void SinglePlay(Ref* pSender);
    void MultiPlay(Ref* pSender);
    void Exit(Ref* pSender);

//  void ImageButton(Ref* pSender);

};
```

Comment: Can you give more details of code to help you?

Comment: What do you mean window screen just show up and turn off right away?

Comment: Usually, the game executes and shows sprites on the screen. However, if I inherit my BaseScene, it does not render anything and the process is terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting here since I dont have enough reputation for commenting as of yet.

Is there any specific reason you want it to be inherited? Cant you just make it a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) instead if it needs to be accessed by objects of all classes in your code?